# Getting a string out of a JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json, rest

I'm trying to get a string out of a JSONObject that I'm receiving from a request to an API.

My JSONObject is as follows:

```
{
  "status":"success",
  "message":"user authenticated",
  "data": { "id":11,
            "username":"2160481",
            "token":"MEznhD8RE1-ykZLOdGs4i9ZfRFQl5h_"
  }
}
```

I've tried some responses I found here, like the getString("token") with no success. I've also tried to create an array with the JSONObject inside and get the string from there, also with no success.

EDIT:

Try 1:

```
String data = response.toString();
JSONObject teste = new JSONObject(data);
String status = teste.getString("status");
System.out.println(status);
```

Try 2:

```
String token = null;
        try {
            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
            arr.put(response);
            JSONObject jObj = arr.getJSONObject(0);
            token = jObj.getString("token");
    System.out.println("---> Token: " + token);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            System.out.println("---> Error:" + e);
        }
```

Try 3:

```
String token = null;
        try {
            token = response.getString("token");
    System.out.println("---> Token: " + token);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        System.out.println("---> Error:" + e);
    }`
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your token field is inside another JSONObject data so you'll have to do the following

```
yourMainObject.getJSONObject("data").getString("token");
```

You can also use optString() method instead of getString if you're not sure that your token will always be present

Answer (score 4):

you should be able to get token by using this.

```
try {
    String data = response.toString();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
    String token = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data").getString("token");
    System.out.println(token);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a library that serialize/deserialize POJO to Java Objects.

Like gson : https://github.com/google/gson